# Retrieve mysql data without any order applied

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, socialengine

I have a table with the name of `actions` with primary key of `action_id`, i am retrieving data from this table as passing my own ordered `action_id`s for example

```
$actionIds = array(5,9,10,21,3,18,4);
$actionsTb = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('actions','activity');

$postSelect = $actionsTb->select()
              ->where('action_id IN(?)', $actionIds)
              ->where('type = ?', 'status')
             ;
```

now the issue is when i get the result back its in ascending order, like ( 3,4,5,9,10,18,21 ) but what i want the order of result as i passed the action ids means don't want to apply any order on the result.
please help me. you can reply with simple query too.

Answer (score 0):

Since your using php, why not use loop to dynamically create where clause here is the code

```
$where = "action_id IN(";

for($x=0; $x<count($actionIds); $x++)
{

    // code for adding comma in every end of id 
    if($x==count($actionIds)-1)
    {
       // found the last data in array add closing parenthesis in IN funtion
       $where.=$actionIds[$x].")";

    }
    else
    {
       $where.=$actionIds[$x].",";
    }
}
```

to test the output echo it first

```
echo $where; //so i think the result is "action_id IN(5,9,10,21,3,18,4)"
```

Here is the complete code

```
$actionIds = array(5,9,10,21,3,18,4);
$where = "action_id IN(";

for($x=0; $x<count($actionIds); $x++)
{

    // code for adding comma in every end of id 
    if($x==count($actionIds)-1)
    {
       $where.=$actionIds[$x].",";
    }
    else
    {
      // add closing parenthesis in IN funtion
       $where.=$actionIds[$x].")";
    }
}

$actionsTb = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('actions','activity');

$postSelect = $actionsTb->select()
          ->where($where)
          ->where('type = ?', 'status')
         ;
```

Comment: Thanks CodeSlayer, i have the order or actions ids, but what i want is that when i pass those ids to query it returns data in ASC order if i don't pass any order, like if i have order of ids like as you said  echo $where; //so i think the result is "action_id IN(5,9,10,21,3,18,4)"
i want result back order as those ids are...but it will return the order ASC like ( 3,4,5,10.. )

Comment: why not add in query the `order by action_id`

Comment: by default it returns ASC order, but i want order as i have passed ids in my Ids array. In mysql if you don't pass any order it will automatically gives you ASC order. I don't want to apply any order i just want results ordered as i have passed Ids array to it.

Comment: i think does not possible in mysql

Comment: One possible solution is that, i run a loop to ids that i am passing and get result one by one and append those result to an array one by one, but it tool a lot of requests to server. :(

Comment: i have suggestion, create temp table the column are id and the rest of the column of your table, and then insert the result one by one, and use the id of tmp table, after the result, delete the value of table

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `zend` coding but following approach may help you.

```
->where( 'FIND_IN_SET( action_id, ? )', $actionIds )
```

I am not sure if zend's `where` converts the *array* `$actionIds` to be *linear item values* i.e. `'5,9,10,21,3,18,4'`. If converted, part of the resulting query would look like:

```
where find_in_set( action_id, '5,9,10,21,3,18,4' )
```

**Example**:

```
mysql> select find_in_set( 18, '5,9,10,21,3,18,4' );
+---------------------------------------+
| find_in_set( 18, '5,9,10,21,3,18,4' ) |
+---------------------------------------+
|                                     6 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Reference**:
  Read `MySQL` documentation on [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: i just want to get the data back in which order i am passing the ids, like if i am passing query ids in this order ( 3,6,2,8,7 )
it gives results in ASC order...i want order as those ids in my array...you can tell me in simple query i will build zend query myself.